# Connecting variable string for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, firebird

How do I connect the variable string for `where` clause in Firebird?

I have two variables type of `SMALLINT`. These variables are incremented after one iteration in while loop.

From these variables I create `DATE` for `where`-> between selection in SQL, something like this (this is my ineffectual try) :

```
 yearmin=extract (year from DATAMIN);
 yearmax=extract (year from DATAMAX);
 monthmin=extract (month from DATAMIN);
 monthmax=extract (month from DATAMAX);
 aktyear=rokmin;
 actmonth=monthmin;

 while  (actyear<=yearmax and actmonth<=monthmax) DO          
 BEGIN
SELECT
[...]
 WHERE (g.GDATAP BETWEEN (:actyear || :actmonth || 01) AND ( :actyear || :actmonth || 30))
[...]

   INTO :Zaw,:Sum;
 actyear=actyear+1;
 actmonth=actmonth+1;
 SUSPEND;
 end
```

Comment: What's this `:actyear` syntax? I've been using SQL Server for a while and I've never encountered it... Also, SUSPEND does not seem to be an SQL Server keyword. Are you sure you are using the right SQL syntax for your DMBS (or that your question is tagged correctly)?

Comment: You have to build a string literal that you can convert to date.

Comment: actyear is temp variable, change every one iteration, for create sql where clause.

Comment: I use Firebird 4.5 as DBMS.

Comment: @Toster, then please fix tags

Comment: Sorry, my fault is firebird 2.5.

Comment: Maybe it is a mistake that creating a variable to do 'where' in the wrong place  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` is [string concatenator](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-concat.html) operator but in the expression `g.GDATAP BETWEEN (:actyear || :actmonth || 01)` you don't have strings but ints. Firebird won't do type conversion for you. So to make it work you have to cast to (var)char, something like

```
cast(:actyear as varchar(4)) || cast(:actmonth as varchar(2)) || '01'
```

You might have to add date separators too, ie

```
cast(:actyear as varchar(4)) || '-' || cast(:actmonth as varchar(2)) || '-01'
```

I don't remember the formats Firebird accepts off the top of my head...

It looks like you construct these dates in the loop, so it might be better to initialize start date before the loop and then increment it by required amount using [`DATEADD()`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html) function.

Comment: Thanks for targeting , it will try to approach it differently .